# Deriving 3rd parties kinship relations from a biunivocal relations dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, loops, apply

I have a table showing bi-univocal kinship relations. In other words, I may have a first row showing the record of a father who has a son, and in the next line, this son shows his relation with his father. But, the father may have another son (son2), so we have another two entries in the table showing the father related to his son2, and son2 linked to the common father. The problem arises when the relation between the two sons does not appear in the table. There is no entry showing son1 is the brother of son2, and I need to derive this from the table. This is my goal, and every individual in the table, has a unique identifier.

What I've been trying to do so far is:

a) To create a list of all the possible kinship roles (in my simplified example above, there would only be 2 roles: father and son).

b) To subset the original table into as many groups as roles are there. As any individual in my example could be a son and/or a father, I create two groups of data. These groups are the elements of a list, so, in other words I created a list by subsetting the roles of the records. In this example, the list has two elements: one for the records where the second person is a son of the first, and another element showing the entries whose second person is a father of the first.

c) My idea was also to subset the previous (two) elements of the list by the first person´s ID. This way, my goal was to create groups of each given ID with all the relations they have. For instance, in our example, we would obtain a group for one ID (the father) formed by two rows: the records of son1 and son2.

d) Once here, the previous subgroup shows that son1 and son2, are brothers. As, again, this is not reported in the original table, my purpose is to derive it through coding creating two new records in the original table which would show that son1 has a brother son2, and son2 has a brother son1.

Given that my dataframe is df and that the variable role of the second person in the relation is Role_2nd, step a) is simple:

```
role <- unique(df$Role_2nd)
```

Step b) is also easy:

```
newRoles <- lapply(role, function(x){subset(df, Role_2nd == x)})
```

After step c) the outcome for the first element of the list -the one I subsetted role="son"- could be like this:

```
ID_First  ID_Second    Role_1st      Role_2nd
569         571          father        son
590         592          father        son
587         597          father        son
597         596          father        son
597         598          father        son
603         604          father        son
603         607          father        son
```

As we can see, the ID 597 has two sons (596 and 598). That means that 596 and 598 are siblings, and I need to derive this relation not present in the original table.

After step d), and subsetting by ID:

```
ID_First  ID_Second    Role_1st      Role_2nd
569         571          father        son

ID_First  ID_Second    Role_1st      Role_2nd
590         592          father        son

ID_First  ID_Second    Role_1st      Role_2nd
587         597          father        son

ID_First  ID_Second    Role_1st      Role_2nd
597         596          father        son
597         598          father        son

ID_First  ID_Second    Role_1st      Role_2nd
603         604          father        son
603         607          father        son
```

(Probably, step d) is dispensable for my final goal).

Following the example, the other element of the list -the one for father as the Role_2nd- should be something like this:

```
Step c)

ID_First   ID_Second       Role_1st       Role_2nd
571          569              son          father
592          590              son          father
597          587              son          father
596          597              son          father
598          597              son          father
604          603              son          father
607          603              son          father


I skip showing step d) also for the second element.
```

Now, here is what I´m stuck with. If all the above is correct -probably there are more simple ways to address the problem-, given that I want to create the role "brother" not present in my original table, my idea is to run the two elements of the list through a loop. Starting with the first, whenever I spot a repeated ID_First (which happens for 597 and 603), then it'd mean that the two individuals they´re linked to (on the one hand -596 & 598, and on the other 604 & 607-) must be "brothers".

But I don´t know how to do this. I don´t know how to spot several equal values of a variable in an element of a list (like spotting two or more equal ID_First in the first element of the list); I don´t know how to subset them; I don't know how to run the loop for each component of each element of the list; I don´t know either how I could code this in a more simple way rather than running an endless loop (here I´m only showing two different roles, but the magnitude of roles in my case is very big -as I´m working with "non western" kinship relations-).

Summing up, the final outcome for my problem would be something like this:

```
ID_First   ID_Second       Role_1st       Role_2nd
596          597              son          father
598          597              son          father
596          598            brother        brother
598          596            brother        brother
604          603              son          father
607          603              son          father
604          607            brother        brother
607          604            brother        brother
```

If anyone can give any tips, they will be very welcome.

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a relational database that properly normalizes your *relations* with an integrated *Families* relation where your desired result is simply a [self-join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm) query on *Persons*.

Specifically, create the following relations with one-to-many relationship between *Families* and *Persons* each at granular level in a relational database such as SQLite (free, open-source, file-level) that R can connect to using RSQLite. Below the role in *Persons* is the absolute (not relative) role in context of whole family such as the *grandfather* being identified.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Families (
  ID INTEGER,
  FAMILY_NAME VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Persons (
  ID INTEGER,
  FAM_ID INTEGER,
  Role VARCHAR(50),
  FOREIGN KEY(FAM_ID) REFERENCES Family(ID)  
);


INSERT INTO Families
VALUES (1, 'Alpha'), (2, 'Bravo'), (3, 'Charlie'), (4, 'Delta');

INSERT INTO Persons
VALUES(569, 1, 'father'),
      (590, 2, 'father'),
      (587, 3, 'grandfather'),
      (597, 3, 'father'),
      (603, 4, 'father'),
      (571, 1, 'son'),
      (592, 2, 'son'),
      (597, 3, 'son'),
      (596, 3, 'son'),
      (598, 3, 'son'),
      (604, 4, 'son'),
      (607, 4, 'son');
```

Then run following query with conditional logic to assign *brother*:

```sql
SELECT p1.ID AS ID1, p2.ID AS ID2,
       CASE 
            WHEN p1.Role = 'son' AND p2.Role = 'son'
            THEN 'brother'
            ELSE p1.Role
       END As Role1,

       CASE 
            WHEN p1.Role = 'son' AND p2.Role = 'son'
            THEN 'brother'
            ELSE p2.Role
       END As Role2

FROM Persons p1
INNER JOIN Persons p2 ON p1.FAM_ID = p2.FAM_ID AND p1.ID > p2.ID

ORDER BY p1.ID, p2.ID;

-- | ID1 | ID2 | Role1   | Role2       |
-- | --- | --- | ------- | ----------- |
-- | 571 | 569 | son     | father      |
-- | 592 | 590 | son     | father      |
-- | 596 | 587 | son     | grandfather |
-- | 597 | 587 | father  | grandfather |
-- | 597 | 587 | son     | grandfather |
-- | 597 | 596 | father  | son         |
-- | 597 | 596 | brother | brother     |
-- | 598 | 587 | son     | grandfather |
-- | 598 | 596 | brother | brother     |
-- | 598 | 597 | son     | father      |
-- | 598 | 597 | brother | brother     |
-- | 604 | 603 | son     | father      |
-- | 607 | 603 | son     | father      |
-- | 607 | 604 | brother | brother     |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gUmktgoXBtTqL1zeG6rUH1/0) *(be sure to click Run for results)*

---

Should you want to stay entirely in R, consider building such corresponding *Families* and *Persons* data frames and run same merge and conditional logic:

Build

```r
Families <- data.frame(ID = seq(1, 4),
                       Family_Name = c("Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta"))

Persons <- data.frame(ID = c(569, 590, 587, 597, 603, 571, 592, 597, 596, 598, 604, 607),
                      Fam_ID = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4),
                      Role = c("father", "father", "grandfather", "father", "father",
                               "son", "son", "son", "son", "son", "son", "son"))
```

Query

```r
# SELF JOIN, AVOIDING REVERSE DUPLICATES
merge_raw <- subset(merge(Persons, Persons, by="Fam_ID", suffixes = c("_1", "_2")), 
                    ID_1 > ID_2) 

# CONDITIONALLY ASSIGN "brother"
final_df <- within(merge_raw, {    
        ID_1 <- ifelse(ID_1 == "son" & ID_2 == "son", "brother", ID_1)
        ID_2 <- ifelse(ID_1 == "son" & ID_2 == "son", "brother", ID_2)
    })

# RE-ORDER ROWS AND COLUMNS
final_df <- with(final_df, data.frame(final_df[order(ID_1, ID_2), 
                                               c("ID_1", "ID_2", "Role_1", "Role_2")],
                                      row.names = NULL))

final_df

#    ID_1 ID_2 Role_1      Role_2
# 1   571  569    son      father
# 2   592  590    son      father
# 3   596  587    son grandfather
# 4   597  587 father grandfather
# 5   597  587    son grandfather
# 6   597  596 father         son
# 7   597  596    son         son
# 8   598  587    son grandfather
# 9   598  596    son         son
# 10  598  597    son      father
# 11  598  597    son         son
# 12  604  603    son      father
# 13  607  603    son      father
# 14  607  604    son         son
```

[View on Rextester](https://rextester.com/GZRFQ82616)

Comment: Likely this answer is due to my recent talk [Leveraging Relational Databses in R](https://raw.githack.com/ParfaitG/WORKSHOPS/master/SatRday/Leverage_Databases_in_R.html)

Comment: Thank you very much @Parfait for such a generous answer.

Comment: No problem, my pleasure on interesting question! Happy coding!